# Pascal program doesn't recognize input (free pascal)

Tags: pascal, freepascal

this is my first time posting so I hope I'm doing it right. I am a beginner and just wrote a simple program that should print the Minimum of 20 numbers and it's position in an array. I'm using free pascal. However if I run it (ctrl+F9) and type in the 20 numbers (with space) and confirm nothing happens. Do I have to press anything else? Or is anything wrong with the program?
Thx in advance!

This the program (it has some German text):

```
program MinimumPositionFinder (input, output);
const
  FELDGROESSE = 20;

type
  tIndexPosition = 1..FELDGROESSE;
  tFeld = array [tIndexPosition] of integer;

var
  Feld : tFeld;
  i: tIndexPosition;
  Minimum : integer;
  Position : tIndexPosition;

begin
  writeln ('Bitte geben Sie',  FELDGROESSE:4 ,  'Zahlen ein.');
  for i := 1 to FELDGROESSE do
    readln (Feld[i]);

  Minimum := Feld[1];

  for i := 2 to FELDGROESSE do
    if Feld[i] < Minimum then
      Feld[i] := Minimum;
  
  for i := 1 to FELDGROESSE do
    if Feld[i] = Minimum then
      Position := i;

  Writeln ('Das Minimum ist' , Minimum:2 , '.' ,
    'Es befindet sich an Position', Position:2 , '.')

end.
```

Comment: Your input is read with `readln`, so please input one number per line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, since you are reading with `readln` ensure you hit enter/return after you input each number. Alternatively, read your numbers in with `read`.

You will also want to record your position at the same time you record the minimum. It's more performant, and likely more correct if you're seeking the first position of the minimum value from the *left*.

```
  Minimum := Feld[1];
  Position := 1;

  for i := 2 to FELDGROESSE do
    if Feld[i] < Minimum then
    begin
      Feld[i] := Minimum;
      Position := i;
    end
```